# HttpRequest usando AngularJS, NodeJS e Express

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, express.js

Sou novato nestas tecnologias e estou tentando fazer uma chamada http(get e post) via html porém está dando erro, ja vi vários tópicos aqui e em outros lugares mas nao consigo fazer funcionar. Alguem consegue me ajudar?

meu index.html

```
<html ng-app="nodeApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Node App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/controllers/nodeAppCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="nodeAppCtrl">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"
                    ng-model="filtroResult">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <input ng-blur="onBlur(formAdd.name)" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="formAdd.name" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="capital" ng-model="formAdd.capital"
            style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <div style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
            <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" ng-click="adicionar(formAdd)">Adicionar</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Capital</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="name in names | filter:filtroResult">
                <td>{{name.name}}</td>
                <td>{{name.capital}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

meu index.js

```
   var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3065;
var app = express();
var appRoutes = require('./routes/appRoutes');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');



app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, sid");
    res.header("Acces-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
    next();
});


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meanDb', { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', appRoutes);

http.createServer(app).listen(port);


console.log("Backend running on port:", port);
```

meu appRoutes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Country = require('../models/dataSchema');

router.post('/create', (req, res) => {
    console.log("ROUTER POST")
    var newCountry = new Country({
        name: req.body.name,
        capital: req.body.capital
    });

    newCountry.save((err, country) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ errmsg: err });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({ msg: country });
        }
    });
});

router.get('/read', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("GET ROUTES")
    Country.find({}, (err, countries) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ errmsg: err });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({ msg: countries });
        }
    });
});

router.put('/update', (req, res, next) => {
    Country.findById(req.body._id, (err, country) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ errmsg: err });
        } else {
            country.name = req.body.name;
            country.capital = req.body.capital;
            country.save((err, country) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).json({ errmsg: err });
                } else {
                    res.status(200).json({ msg: country });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

router.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    Country.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, country) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ errmsg: err });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({ msg: country });
        }
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

meu nodeAppCtrl.js

```
angular.module("nodeApp").controller("nodeAppCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.app = "node app";
    $scope.names = [{name:"Brazil",capital:"Brasilia"},
                    {name:"Pernambuco", capital:"Recife"}];
    $scope.status = "";

    $scope.onBlur = function(campo){
        if(campo.toUpperCase == "brazil".toUpperCase || campo.toUpperCase == "brasil".toUpperCase){
            $scope.formAdd.capital = "Brasilia"
        }else if(campo == ""){
            delete $scope.formAdd.capital
        }
    }

    $scope.adicionar = function (request) {
        $http.post('localhost:3065/create', request)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.status = "sucesso";
        }).catch(function (err) {
            $scope.status = "error";
            console.log(err);
        });

    };

});
```

Minha classe respectiva ao Country

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var countrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    capital: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('country', countrySchema);
```

---

Quando eu clico no botao ele chama o método $scope.adicionar e sempre cai no catch, o que eu percebi é que ele nao entra no meu Router, já pelo postman ele vai direto para o Router e funciona.

Comment: O que acontece que não funciona? Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Onde está o código da classe `Country`?

Comment: Editei a postagem com o erro que acontece e o fonte respectivo ao Country.